# Git command to see if repository has changed (no diff)

Tags: git, github

say I `clone` a git repo locally... time goes by and I want to see if anything has changed back at the origin... but i don't, necessarily, want to `fetch` or `pull`...yet.

what's the command for seeing a list of commits SINCE i last pulled...or just the fact that there HAVE been some commits since I last pulled?

i don't want overhead of `diff` in this case...

Comment: Is it bandwidth that prevents you from wanting to fetch?

Comment: I guess, as I get accustom to git, I am afraid of my current work being overwritten by a fetch.

Answer (score 2):

git remote show origin

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git fetch --dry-run
```

Comment: This actually fetches all of the objects; it just doesn't update the remote branches. That may not be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least fetch, without that the repo will have no information about the remote repository. `git diff --summary` will then show you a short summary of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

get all of the commits into local tracking branch:
`git fetch`

list all of the changes between tracking branch and HEAD:
`git log origin/master HEAD`